# Google SQL Cloud not recognizing newly created user for postgresql database

Tags: google-cloud-platform, postgresql

I created `dbadmin` at the Google SQL Cloud console, and `dbadmin` using the command line interface. This is an instance of a client of mine. We need a db dump (we're trying to do pg_dump) so we can export the db to our own server at digital ocean. GCP seems to be overly complicated (and overpriced).

Anyway I'll attach an image with redacted db and instance names.

[image: gcloud]

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating a "dbadmin" user and I couldn't connect to the instance. it seems that this exact name have some issues. try to create another user name and export accordingly.